# Не удается задать свойство объекта , так как он находится в состоянии "только чтение"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Почему когда я пытаюсь возвратить координаты sender.ellipse-а относительно canvas, выходит ошибка "Дополнительные сведения: Не удается задать свойство объекта "", так как он находится в состоянии "только чтение"."?

```
private void Ellipse_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    m.Transform = (Transform)(sender as Ellipse).TransformToAncestor(canvas);
    IntersectionDetail khg = m.FillContainsWithDetail(g);
}
```

У меня вот ещё есть ...

```
foreach (Ellipse tb in FindVisualChildren<Ellipse>(canvas))
{
            var g = tb.RenderedGeometry;
            g.Transform = (Transform)tb.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
}
```

Вот здесь почему-то нет ошибок @VladD.
А вот так ...

```
foreach (Ellipse tb in FindVisualChildren<Ellipse>(canvas))
{
            var g = tb.RenderedGeometry;
            g.Transform = (Transform)tb.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
}
            var m = (sender as Ellipse).RenderedGeometry;
            m.Transform = (Transform)(sender as Ellipse).TransformToAncestor(canvas);
```

... ошибка (((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
в System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
в System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
в System.Windows.Media.Geometry.set_Transform(Transform value)
в visualprogramming.MainWindow.Ellipse_OnMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) в D:\Новая папка\YandexDisk\VisualProgramming\MainWindow.xaml.cs:строка 351
в System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
в System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
в System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Synchronize()
в System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.ChangeMouseCapture(IInputElement mouseCapture, IMouseInputProvider providerCapture, CaptureMode captureMode, Int32 timestamp)
в System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Capture(IInputElement element, CaptureMode captureMode)
в System.Windows.UIElement.CaptureMouse()
в visualprogramming.MainWindow.module_mouseleftbtnDOWN(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) в D:\Новая папка\YandexDisk\VisualProgramming\MainWindow.xaml.cs:строка 257
в System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
в System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
в System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
в System.Windows.UIElement.OnPreviewMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
в System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
в System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
в System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
в System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
в System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
в System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
в System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
в System.Windows.Application.Run()
в visualprogramming.App.Main() в D:\Новая папка\YandexDisk\VisualProgramming\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:строка 0
в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подождите а вот где у меня вылазит ошибка IsFreezen = true
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну вот посмотрите весь метод без всяких "вырезок", может вам поможет ...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse { Width = 20, Height = 20, StrokeThickness = 2 };

ellipse.Name = ("ellipse" + ++_counter);
ellipse.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
ellipse.Stroke = (UI as Ellipse).Stroke;
ellipse.Fill = Brushes.White;
ellipse.MouseMove += Ellipse_OnMouseMove;
ellipse.MouseLeftButtonUp += Ellipse_OnMouseLeftButtonUp;

var dsEffect = new DropShadowEffect();
dsEffect.BlurRadius = 7d;
dsEffect.ShadowDepth = 0d;
dsEffect.Opacity = 0.8;
ellipse.Effect = dsEffect;

canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas).X);
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas).Y);




Line line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 2, Stroke = (UI as Ellipse).Fill };
line.IsHitTestVisible = false;
line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
line.X1 = pt.X;
line.Y1 = pt.Y;
line.X2 = Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
line.Y2 = Canvas.GetTop(ellipse);
canvas.Children.Add(line);
ellipse.Tag = line;
_isDrag = true;
ellipse.CaptureMouse();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33852/discussion-on-question-by-alex-rudenkiy------).